# Issue when rendering a Jbuilder json object as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am developing in student tracking website in RoR. In model I have following code to build json

```
self.as_json
  json = Jbuilder.new do |j|
    j.courses student_courses do |course|
      j.(course, :id, :name)
      j.students students, :name
    end
  end.target!
  puts json
  return json
end
```

My controller code is

```
render json: {
  courses: course.as_json,
}
```

and produces

```
{"courses":[
"{\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"english\",\"students\": [{\"name\": \"ALison\"},{\"name\": \"Robert\"}]
},{...}...  ]"
```

instead of

```
 "courses" : [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "english",
    "students": [
        {"name": "ALison"},
        {"name": "Robert"}]
}, {..},...    
]
```

It is adding escape character(/) before every double quotes. How can I solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this to generate as alternative

```
   course.to_json(:include => { :students => { :only => :name } })
```

Comment: Yes. your alternative is a good one. But can you please tell me a solution using Jbuilder as I need to some changes in the format of json